# Is there a 'rc' configuration file for grep/egrep? (~/.egreprc?)

Tags: grep, configuration, alias, options

I usually use `grep` when developing, and there are some extensions that I always want to exclude (like `*.pyc`).

Is it possible to create a `~/.egreprc` or something like that, and add filtering to exclude `pyc` files from all results?

Is this possible, or will I have to create an alias for using `grep` in this manner, and call the alias instead of `grep`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

No, there's no rc file for grep.

GNU grep 2.4 through 2.21 applied options from the environment variable `GREP_OPTIONS`, but more recent versions no longer honor it.

For interactive use, define an alias in your shell initialization file (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc`). I use a variant of the following:

```
alias regrep='grep -Er --exclude=*~ --exclude=*.pyc --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.svn'
```

If you call the alias `grep`, and you occasionally want to call `grep` without the options, type `\grep`. The backslash bypasses the alias.

Comment: This is THE answer I was looking for. I think I'll read more about ~/.profile. @Gilles, you're the man. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Considering there are two possibilites to do this (GREP_OPTIONS and alias grep): Is one of them preferred? Why or why not?

Comment: @Legate: An important difference is that `GREP_OPTIONS` will affect `grep` calls in scripts, while an alias won't. So `GREP_OPTIONS` should be used sparingly. The most common use is for `--color=auto`, which is in principle harmless in scripts because it only takes effect if the output is a terminal.

Comment: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script

Comment: @oalders I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', thanks! In that case I will delete my comment. :)

Answer (score 3):

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) can do what you want and more.

It will ignore binary files by default and you can tell it to ignore other filetypes as you want `--notext`, `--nohtml`, etc. It has the ability to define an rc file too so you can customize it with your own types.

Comment: I'm using ack too, but I didn't like it. It's indeed fast, but it's not available in all installations, so I was thinking about grep. Thanks!

Comment: ack is a single Perl program, downloadable as a plain text file.  If you want, you can go to http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone and cut & paste the contents into a file.  I specifically made it so that it is available _anywhere_ you can run Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question. But grep has an option to ignore all binary files including *.pyc. The option is `-I`

```
grep -rI hello .
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in GNU `grep`/`egrep`, there isn't.

You probably want a specially-named alias or script to do this anyway, because someday later you might find yourself very confused when trying to look in something that you forgot matches your special configuration.

Comment: `GREP_OPTIONS` in `~/.profile` comes close.

Comment: @Gilles — good point. In fact, I forgot that I have that set myself for `--color=auto`!

Answer (score 1):

Since at least 2016 (according to [Steven Penny's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8214/is-there-a-rc-configuration-file-for-grep-egrep-egreprc#comment571274_8218)), the grep-recommended way of doing this is with an alias or script:

```
$ export GREP_OPTIONS="--exclude='*~'"
$ grep -r someStringThatDoesNotExist
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
$
```